# How to check missing double codes within csv file using shell script?

Tags: shell

I have csv file. That file contains 21 fields. one field had double quotes opened but the closing double quote is missing in one of the record in file

eg: 422556565,22562546-2562625,postalcode,"waiting list

In the above example closing double code has missed in last field. I want to check whether any opening or closing double codes are missing in that file. if it is missing, need record number. For example if closing or opening double codes are missing in 70th record, i need the exact record number

Comment: Advance Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you need it to be done in a shell script? It does not look like a task that would be easy to do in, say, bash, whereas it would be pretty easy in, say, python (you can replace bash and python with you favorite shell language and scripting language).

Comment: Our application is having only bash script. That's why i asked in bash script

Comment: Dear BlackBeans, could you please write code in python for this task? If yes , please share here.

Comment: So do you only want to know whether there are lines where  the number of double quotes is odd, or do you want to know whether your file is well-formed CSV? Further, if you are looking for a bash solution, please tag your question as _bash_. If you tag it only as _shell_, it means that you are looking for a solution using POSIX shell.

Comment: Yes correct i want to know only whether there are lines where the number of double quotes is odd. Need solution in bash script

Comment: Hi user1934428, Please help for the above task